# Can we use encryption for journey builder, automation and HTML contents in Marketing cloud

Tags: automation, encryption, content

I just want to encrypt my automation and codes in SFMC is this possible and how it cane be done. I know we can encrypt the data but I am looking for encryption of automation, journey and content.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this is possible today.